# How to work out of a dialogBox?

Tags: gwt, dialog

i'm using gwt and when my browser shows me a element from type DialogBox I want to work out of this dialog too. But the dialog locks it. Is there a option to unlock the background and work outter the dialog?

Comment: What are you working on , From the tag I am guessing you are using Google Web tool kit, Please make your question more clear. Is it an alert dialog or is it a modal Dialog box ?

Comment: @blackSheep - Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to clarify your question. As it stands there's no way for anyone to understand what you're asking, much less help you out.

Comment: sorry, i thought it was clearly that my question is about the gwt DialogBox because i take the gwt-Tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tags I assume that you are using [DialogBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html), right? If so then use `setModal(false)` to prevent modal dialog behavior.

Comment: yes! :-) thank you,setModal is what i'm searched